# TokenValidationParameters ignored if policy is added to Authorise attribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt, bearer-token, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using AspNetCore.All 2.0

I have a controller that uses the Authorize attribute like so:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme]
```

When I pass a JWT token it fails as expected because it's expired. However when I add a policy like below it always passes with a 200. I should still get a 401 because it's an expired token, right? What could I be doing wrong?

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Policy = "Over21")]
```

Below are my token validation parameters. Please note that adding the policy doesn't just affect the expiration it could be any of the parameters

```
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            cfg.SaveToken = true;

            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidIssuer = "https://localhost",
                ValidAudience = "https://localhost",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("someveryveryveryverylongkey")),                    
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero

            };
        });
```

Comment: ok seems to work when I add two authorise attributes

Comment: [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [Authorize(Policy = "Over21")]

Comment: ok sticking two things in one Authorise attribute may cause it to be an OR. AuthenticationsScheme or Policy21. Putting them in two Authorize Attributes make an AND https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles

Comment: `ValidateIssuer = false` means `ValidIssuer = "https://localhost"` is ignored. Are you sure you'd want that?